# How to Retrieve Selected Value of RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to read those selected items using datareader and make the radiobutton enabled in the list.

```
Radiobuttonlist1.Text=??
```

Comment: Selected Item using datareader?? The user selects an item and not a DataReader. So you should say what you really want. The [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) has a [SelectedItem property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter `SelectedItem` can return the `text` or the `value` but it certainly doesn't set the value.

Comment: @JonH: The question is "how to retrieve/read..." and not "how to set...". That is what has confused me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - But the end of it says `and make the radiobutton enabled in the list`.

Comment: TimSchmelter - i do agree the question needs rewording / editing.  @Sammy please fix it to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Radiobuttonlist1.SelectedValue = YourValue`

So if you have a reader:

`reader("MyColumn")`

Then you can do:

`RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = CType(reader("MyColumn"), Integer) 'is my col an integer`

If you want to display the item selected or the text:

For text:

`RadiobuttonList1.SelectedItem.Text 'for text`

For value:

`RadiobuttonList1.SelectedItem.Value 'for value`